# How do I convert image path to image object I can use ImageChops on?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to add all the .tiff files in a directory together using ImageChops, but I keep on getting the error 'IOError: cannot identify image file'. I thought it was just a problem with trying to use a file path instead of an image object, but similar codes in other places don't have this problem.

```
def imadd():  #subcommand
    img1=Image.new('RGB',(2048, 2048))
    img1.save("summation.tif")
    for file in os.listdir(directoryname):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.tif'):
           im2 = Image.open("summation.tif", mode='r')
           im3 = Image.open(os.path.join(directoryname, file))
           finalimg = ImageChops.add(im2, im3, 1, 0)
           finalimg.save("summation.tif")
```

By trail and error, all the parts work except:

im3 = Image.open(os.path.join(directoryname, file)).

I also tried using glob.glob(), but that still returns the same error.

Comment: It might be the case PIL does not support some specific TIF files you have. Can you link to one of them that causes the error ?

Comment: They are 8Mb,  2048x2048 pixel .TIFF files:  [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3VsROw1WdB4NVZpMGV2WlBCZGs) I'm rewriting an outdated x-ray diffraction processing program using python.

Comment: That file is a 16 bpp grayscale TIFF which opens just fine with PIL 1.1.7. Are you using the same version ?

Comment: It is interesting that with a certain program I can see white points in this image, but in other programs I have they all say this is a single flat black image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can open and show 16 bit tiffs with PIL, ImageChops doesn't work. matplotlib and scipy have many more tools available.

Also im3 = Image.open(os.path.join(directoryname, file)) needs to be Image.open(unicode(os.path.join(directoryname, file)))